# How to construct a weighted classification system with a many-to-one relationship with the classifications

Tags: classification

So I am at this hurdle in a project to where I can't seem to make any sense of.

I have a scanning system. Let's say that it tracks widgets with 5 possible defects. Any widget can have 0 or all of the possible defects.

A batch of widgets will come in, and each one will be scanned. If a widget has 1 or more defects, it counts as a match, and will be counted towards the total ratio of numbers of widgets with a defect. If the ratio exceeds 25%, the entire batch will be denied.

The issue is, not all defects are alike. defect #1 is not nearly as bad as defect #5. So I'm trying to construct a weighted system that takes each individual defect's effective contribution to the population's "defectedness", taking into consideration the possibility that any widget can have more than one defect and each potential defect has varying degrees of severity.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Apologies on the lack of clarity. I guess I'm just looking for a direction or method to look into in terms of developing a weighted classification system that works for the information described above, where defect #5 would contribute more significantly to the decision on if the batch is wiped out than defect #1 would

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to modify the cost function of your classifier, i.e. increase the loss / penalty of misclassifying (not detecting) defect #5.

I don't know which classifier / software you are using so in case this is not easy to archive or implement, you could also try to over-sample the samples with defect #5 by a some factor as this will likely shift the decision boundary to be less permissive for defect #5 samples.

You could also implement a different (binary) classifier for each error and then weight their outputs differently, according to the severity of the predicted effect.

I hope I understood you problem correctly and these approaches apply in your case.

Comment: On the chance of not detecting, let's assume there is always 100% chance of correctly identifying every defect for each widget. No defects would ever be missed

Comment: You've written that "if a widget has 1 or more defects, it counts as a match, and will be counted towards the total ratio of numbers of widgets with a defect."

Well, this sound very binary to me, i.e. if it has any defect, it labeled 'defect' and that's it. 

If some defects are more relevant than others, say the threshold for the defect/total is 0.25 for defect #1 and 0.1 for defect #5, then you simply need to score them according, i.e. multiply the number of defect #5 samples by some factor. In any way, **you** need to decide for a threshold.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking this question as answered though.